# Green Lines in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

What is the significance of these green lines in Inno Setup script?
What happens if these are removed??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines of text in the script (in sections like `[Files]`) that start with:

- `;`
- `//`

These are considered as [comments](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptformatoverview.htm) and they don't do anything. The `[Code]` section has its own style of comments too.

---

> What happens if these are removed??

Since they are commented out lines of script, you have two choices:

1. Delete the comments if they are obsolete.
2. Retain then for reference.

At the end of the day we don't know why you originally had those lines in your script and / or why or why someone decided to comment them out.